# MongoDB aggregate - how to make deep level lookup

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

i have a collection clinics with eventsIds array like that :

```
clinics : [
 {"_id": "clinicId1",
  "eventsIds" :[
       "eventId1","eventId2"
   ]
  }
]
```

and events collection :

```
{"_id" : "eventId1" : customerId:"customerId1"},
{"_id" : "eventId2" : customerId:"customerId2"},
```

and customer collection :

```
{"_id" : "customerId1" : name:"some_name"},
{"_id" : "customerId2" : name:"some_name"},
```

what i need is a clinic item :

```
  clinic: {
    "id":"clinicId1",
    "events":[
      "eventId1":{customer:{"_id" : "customerId1" : name:"some_name"}},
       "eventId2":{customer:{"_id" : "customerId2" : name:"some_name"}}
    ]
  }
```

i managed to make a aggregate lookup to create events array inside the clinic item but not the second step to retrieve the customer details

how can i achieve that ?

Thanks !